How to highlight the chapter, section, subsection with different colors?
So, I'm making short notes for physics and I'm writing the my notes in twocolumn and the documentclass is book. i want to highlight(or have some different color at the background) the chapter, section and subsection. I've tried running the \sethlcolor commands but I'm unable to highlight the chapter and section. Any suggestions?

Welcome! Can you post a small example of the code you're using? \sethlcolor is not a standard command.

\chapterfont{\color{coolblack}}
\sectionfont{\color{cobalt} \sethlcolor{blue!20}}
i tried this it didn't workout.
and
\sethlcolor{yellow!30}
is just useful when it comes to highlighting the text

See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/ for some help editing your question. None of the commands you mention using are standard LaTeX.
